# How to translate a word/sentence into an imaginary language using coded parameters?

Tags: python, loops

I am coding a program that takes a single word in English and translates it into the imaginary language, elvish. What I need to do is have a sentence be translated, but I do not know how I could do that. So far, my program only works for a single word. Also, I need the program to start with the sentence: "Elcómewó óten heten Igpén Lvísheá ránslátórtë! (Welcome to the Pig Elvish translator!)".

However, I don't know how to display this in the beginning. I know a series of loops are needed, but I do not understand for/while loops the way I thought I did to be able to accomplish this. Finally, once the program is run and the user output is displayed, I need to be able to ask the user if they want to translate another word into elvish, and if so, go through the code again.

```
# User Input: Ask user for a word

WordToBeTranslated = input("Please enter a word you would like to translate: ")
WordToBeTranslatedLower = WordToBeTranslated.lower()

# Condition #1: Moving the First Letter to the end

elvish = WordToBeTranslatedLower[1:] + WordToBeTranslatedLower[0]

# Condition #2 + #3: Appending a Vowel / Appending 'en' to the end of a word

vowel = ['a', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
import random
randomVowel = random.choice(vowel)
list = []
list.append(WordToBeTranslated)
if len(WordToBeTranslated) >= 4:
    elvish += randomVowel

else:
    elvish = elvish + 'en'

# Condition #4: change all k's to c's

elvish = elvish.replace('k', 'c')

# Condition #5: Replace 'e' at end of the word with ë

if elvish[-1] == 'e':
    elvish = elvish[:-1] + 'ë'


# Condition #6: Capitalization
# Part of Condition #6 was achieved in Condition #1

elvishFinal = elvish.capitalize()
print("\"" + WordToBeTranslated + "\"", "in elvish is:", elvishFinal)

newWord = input("Would you like to translate another word? (y/n): ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, try this which is just a simple code arrangement.

First, the translator function wrapper:

```
def elvish_translator(input_sentence):
  WordToBeTranslatedLower = input_sentence.lower()

  # Condition #1: Moving the First Letter to the end
  elvish = WordToBeTranslatedLower[1:] + WordToBeTranslatedLower[0]

  # Condition #2 + #3: Appending a Vowel / Appending 'en' to the end of a word
  vowel = ['a', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  import random
  randomVowel = random.choice(vowel)
  list = []
  list.append(WordToBeTranslated)
  if len(WordToBeTranslated) >= 4:
      elvish += randomVowel
  else:
      elvish = elvish + 'en'

  # Condition #4: change all k's to c's
  elvish = elvish.replace('k', 'c')

  # Condition #5: Replace 'e' at end of the word with ë
  if elvish[-1] == 'e':
      elvish = elvish[:-1] + 'ë'

  # Condition #6: Capitalization
  # Part of Condition #6 was achieved in Condition #1
  elvishFinal = elvish.capitalize()

  print("  \"" + WordToBeTranslated + "\"", "in elvish is:", elvishFinal)
```

Then the user input function which keeps asking the user the y/n and only y/n:

```
def user_choice_function():
  input_user = input("\nWould you like to translate another word? (y/n): ")
  while input_user not in ['y', 'n']:
      input_user = input("  Input error. Please choose between yes (y) or no (n). Try again: ")

  return input_user
```

And finally, the main:

```
print("Elcómewó óten heten Igpén Lvísheá ránslátórtë! (Welcome to the Pig Elvish translator!)\n")
user_choice = 'y'
while user_choice == 'y':
  WordToBeTranslated = input("Please enter a word you would like to translate: ")
  elvish_translator(WordToBeTranslated)
  user_choice = user_choice_function()
```

Example:

```
"""
Elcómewó óten heten Igpén Lvísheá ránslátórtë! (Welcome to the Pig Elvish translator!)

Please enter a word you would like to translate: Hello world!
  "Hello world!" in elvish is: Ello world!hu

Would you like to translate another word? (y/n): yes
  Input error. Please choose between yes (y) or no (n). Try again: y
Please enter a word you would like to translate: Hello StackOverflow!
  "Hello StackOverflow!" in elvish is: Ello staccoverflow!hu

Would you like to translate another word? (y/n): n
"""
```